# Hosting WCF Web Service on IIS Throws Argument Exception When Navigating to SVC File

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, iis-express

I'm trying to host a WCF web service on IIS, but when I navigate to a virtual svc file, I receive the following argument and service activation exception respectively:

> This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There
> can be at most one address per scheme in this collection...
>
> The service '/SidService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception
> during compilation.  The exception message is: This collection already
> contains an address with scheme http.

I'm able to run it locally using IIS express and navigate successfully to the svc file. It's when the project is deployed to the server running IIS 7.5 that the issue occurs.

I'm using a declarative syntax to configure the web service, so nothing is being configured programatically.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Services.SidManager"
               behaviorConfiguration="SidManagerBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="Contracts.ISidService"
                  bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfig"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBindingConfig" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000">
          <reliableSession enabled="true"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SidManagerBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="100"
                             maxConcurrentCalls="16"
                             maxConcurrentInstances="116"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <serviceActivations>
        <add service="Services.SidManager" 
             relativeAddress="SidService.svc" />
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Part of the error message suggested setting the multipleSiteBindingsEnabled property to true, but enabling multiple site bindings wasn't successful.

Also, I'm only using the wsHttpBinding would I even need enable multiple site bindings or have multiple base address prefix filters?

Is there a different configuration I need to use for IIS 7.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I was able to determine IIS had two bindings. Adding a `<baseAddressPrefixFilters>` element to the `<serviceHostingEnvironment>`, resolved the issue.
I found a [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9e248455-1c4d-4c5c-851c-79d9c1631e21/there-can-be-at-most-one-address-per-scheme-in-this-collection?forum=wcf) on MSDN's forums that helped me my solution.

Here's the code I implemented:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix="http://subdomain.domain.name:port/"/>
    </baseAddressPrefixFilters>

    ...

</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```